# Any file or folder on the desktop gets duplicated, why is that? [win 11 home]

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-11

I was messing with the registry keys trying to change the user folder name, but eventually created a new admin user & deleted the old ones.

Now, when ever I copy, move or make a new folder or file on the desktop only, it shows up as 2 exact usable copies, they have the same location & name on the desktop.

But when deleting one of them the other gets removed too with the first refresh!

I have tried fixing any corrupted files by the commands: "sfc/scannow" & "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" but it fixed some corrupt files but did not fix the underlying issue.

Here are some screenshots for the desktop and the registry settings that I suspect might be the cause:

[image: Duplicates]

[image: Registry values]

Any ideas how to fix this? I'm trying to avoid another reinstall!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Registry Editor, go to the following branch:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

Double-click "Common Desktop" and set its data to:

```
%PUBLIC%\Desktop
```

Likewise, fix the paths for Music, Pictures, Videos, etc.

Log off/log back in.

**References:**

- [Fix for Duplicate Desktop Icons in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/duplicate-desktop-icons-in-windows/)
- [Duplicate and Triplicate desktop icons](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/bd5df4a0-439a-4f68-8f84-cb8744127357/duplicate-and-triplicate-desktop-icons?forum=itprovistadesktopui)

[image]